# How do I add a second Windows boot drive to Grub Customizer?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, ssd

I currently have a 32 Gb eMMC drive and a 120 Gb SSD drive in my laptop. The 32 Gb came with Windows installed when I got the laptop, and has the manufacturer's partitions which I do not want to get rid of yet. I did a clean install of Windows on the SSD, then shrunk it by 20 Gb, which I used to install Ubuntu. However, in the Grub menu I see when I turn on my computer, I see only an option to boot Windows from the eMMC, not the SSD Windows partition. How do I add an option to boot Windows from the SSD?

Comment: Did you install the second Windows in UEFI mode?  All oses should be in the same mode.

Comment: It's strange, in UEFI mode only one Windows Boot Manager ever shows up in the Boot Menu. If I want to change which Windows it is, I have to boot up into Advanced Startup and choose Boot from a Different Operating System.

Comment: I installed Windows on the SSD from a USB stick.

Comment: Ah, I see. Even though Grub says it's going to boot Windows from the eMMc, it actually just boots from whichever one I last booted from, so that mostly resolves my issue. However, I'd still like to see both Windows drives in Grub-- is there any way to do that?

Comment: Did you run sudo update-grub after the second Windows installation?  That should pick it up, but you might need to use drivemap to fool Windows into thinking it's on the first disk for it to actually boot -- install might do that, check the generated grub.cfg.

Comment: Do you have two ESP - efi system partitions, once on each drive? Are both drives gpt? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

All your installed operating systems should be in the same mode: UEFI or legacy.  New machines with Windows 8+ preinstalled have been UEFI for about 5 years, but a custom built machine, one upgraded from Windows 7, could be in either mode, even if the machine is UEFI. Further, UEFI Windows requires GPT partitioning on the disk, not MSDOS partitioning.   UEFI mode boots require an EFI partition for the bootloaders.

The Ubuntu install media can boot in either mode, UEFI or legacy, depending upon the settings in your BIOS/UEFI Settings.  So determine what mode your first Windows is in, then check that your BIOS boot settings will allow the installer to boot in that mode.

I don't know how to force a Windows installation mode -- but if your second Windows installation is in the wrong mode, your Ubuntu installation will only find one of them (the one which matches Ubuntu's mode).  This seems to match what you are seeing.

Booting installations of Windows from two different disks also requires fooling the second disk Windows into thinking it is on the first disk.  I don't know if the Ubuntu installer will actually provide the diskmap hd0 hd1 and   diskmap hd1 hd0 lines in grub.cfg  to "flip" the disks, you might have to add them yourself by editing one of the /etc/grub.d files to provide a custom Windows boot.

Comment: How you boot install media, both Windows & Ubuntu either UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. Related to UEFI & BIOS not being compatible and once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or can only boot from UEFI if installs not all in same mode.